# Best way to find similar groups in a dataset based on 1 variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, cluster-analysis

```
gfg_data <- data.frame(
  year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022),
  Timings = c(5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 4, 11, 13, 15, 14, 17, 12)
)
```

This is a much more simplified dataset compared to what I'm using. Essentially, I'd like to find out the years that are most similar in terms of timings. So, I'd like to be able to see that 2019 and 2020 are similar and 2021/2022 are similar. My original dataset has 500 variables, so it won't be as simple as looking through the data and noting down what is similar.

Comment: How do you define "similar"? distance between any two values?

Comment: Yes, distance between two values

Comment: Then what is the distance as the threshold?

Comment: I'd say around 5 units

Comment: You should put the distance criteria into your question

Answer (score 1):

Given distance `5` (exclusive) as the threshold for clustering the values, you can try `igraph` like below

```
library(igraph)

df %>%
  mutate(group = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(dist(Timings)) < 5, "undirected") %>%
    components() %>%
    membership())
```

which gives

```
   year Timings group
1  2019       5     1
2  2019       6     1
3  2019       4     1
4  2020       2     1
5  2020       3     1
6  2020       4     1
7  2021      11     2
8  2021      13     2
9  2021      15     2
10 2022      14     2
11 2022      17     2
12 2022      12     2
```

---

If you already have the number of clusters in you mind, say, `2`, you can use `kmeans` like below

```
> transform(df, group = as.integer(factor(kmeans(Timings, 2)$cluster)))
   year Timings group
1  2019       5     1
2  2019       6     1
3  2019       4     1
4  2020       2     1
5  2020       3     1
6  2020       4     1
7  2021      11     2
8  2021      13     2
9  2021      15     2
10 2022      14     2
11 2022      17     2
12 2022      12     2
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) max absolute diff** Assuming that each year has the same number of rows in consistent order we can calculate the max absolute difference between the timings in each pair of years and then sort the results.  `m` is a matrix with one column per year and `out` is a vector of the maximum absolute differences for each pair. `outDF` represents `out` as a data frame.  From `outDF` and the bar plot we see that 2019/2020 and 2021/2022 are closer to each other than the other pairs.

```
maxabs <- function(ix, i = ix[1], j = ix[2]) max(abs(m[, i] - m[, j]))

m <- do.call("cbind", with(gfg_data, split(Timings, year)))
out <- combn(colnames(m), 2, maxabs)
names(out) <- combn(colnames(m), 2, paste, collapse = ":")
outDF <- stack(sort(out))[2:1]
outDF
##         ind values
## 1 2019:2020      3
## 2 2021:2022      4
## 3 2019:2021     11
## 4 2019:2022     11
## 5 2020:2021     11
## 6 2020:2022     14

with(outDF, barplot(values, names = ind))
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) multcomp**  Another possibility is to use multcomp to perform multiple comparison significance tests on the group means.  The data frame with years and letters shows that 2019 and 2020 are not significantly different and similarly for 2021 and 2022.  The plot at the end shows boxplots for each year and with the significance grouping lettrers above each one at the top.

```
library(multcomp)

mdl <- lm(Timings ~ year, transform(gfg_data, year = factor(year)))
comp <- glht(mdl, mcp(year = "Tukey"))
CLD <- cld(comp)
stack(CLD$mcletters$monospacedLetters)[2:1]
##    ind values
## 1 2019     a 
## 2 2020     a 
## 3 2021      b
## 4 2022      b

plot(CLD)
```

[image: screenshot]

**3) emmeans** Using emmeans we can create a plot of confidence intervals for each pair mean differences such that the years in those pairs who interval crosses zero are not significantly different.  `mdl` is from above.

```
library(emmeans)
p <- pairs(emmeans(mdl, "year"), adjust = "tukey")
plot(p)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

An approach is using hierarchical clustering, e.g. with `hclust` using `k=2`

```
cbind(gfg_data, grp = cutree(hclust(dist(gfg_data$Timings)), k=2))
   year Timings grp
1  2019       5   1
2  2019       6   1
3  2019       4   1
4  2020       2   1
5  2020       3   1
6  2020       4   1
7  2021      11   2
8  2021      13   2
9  2021      15   2
10 2022      14   2
11 2022      17   2
12 2022      12   2
```

or with height `h=7` that can be found by inspecting the actual clustering (red line is at 7).

```
plot(hclust(dist(gfg_data$Timings)))
lines(c(1,10), c(7,7), col="red", lw=3)
```

[image: hclust plot]

```
cbind(gfg_data, grp = cutree(hclust(dist(gfg_data$Timings)), h=7))
   year Timings grp
1  2019       5   1
2  2019       6   1
3  2019       4   1
4  2020       2   1
5  2020       3   1
6  2020       4   1
7  2021      11   2
8  2021      13   2
9  2021      15   2
10 2022      14   2
11 2022      17   2
12 2022      12   2
```